4th roots of complex number 7 + 24i
I was solving a complex numbers worksheet and came across a 4th root question of the complex number $z = 7 + 24i$, with the answer in cartesian form. I got that the modulus was 25, and the argument was $\arctan(\frac{24}{7}),$ but when solving with these, my answer it differed from the format of the actual answer.
In polar form, my complex number was written as follows:
$25 \times cis(73.3)$
I'll use one of my roots as an example of the difference: $2.121+0.692i.$
I used the rule $$z_k = \sqrt[n]r \left[\cos\frac{\theta + 360k}n + i  \sin\frac{\theta + 360k}n\right],  k = 0, 1, 2, ... ,(n-1)$$ to solve this question.
Question (part b)
Actual Answer

Please use MathJax.

You use $z=7+24i$ and later write $z=...$ for the example fourth root. Don't reuse variables like that.

Also, when we do math here, by default, we do not use degrees here, unless you explicitly say so. Replace $360$ with $2\pi$ or state somewhere your angles are in degrees.

So ... is this right... $$\arctan\frac{24}{7} =4\arctan\frac13$$

It's not clear what your question is here. You've got $\theta,$ do you know $r?$

@ThomasAndrews yes I said the modulus was 25 (aka r)

@GEdgar I'll try that way thanks

@ThomasAndrews also thanks for the tips/edits

(7,24,25) is a Pythagorean triple. So is (3,4,5). What are the squares of $3+4i$   and $4+3i$

$\arctan(24/7)$ is closer to $73.7^\circ$ than to $73.3^\circ$

take square root twice....First, we want real $x,y$   such that $(x+iy)^2  = 7 + 24 i,$   or
$$   x^2 - y^2  = 7 \; , \; \; \; 2xy = 24  $$
The latter gives us $y = \frac{12}{x}, $  so the first becomes
$$  x^2 - \frac{144}{x^2}  = 7,$$
$$  x^4 - 144 = 7 x^2  $$
$$ x^4 - 7 x^2 - 144 = 0$$
From the quadratic formula we get
$$ x^2 = \frac{7 \pm \sqrt{49 + 576}}{2} = \frac{7 \pm \sqrt{625}}{2} = \frac{7 \pm 25}{2} = \frac{32 \; , \; -18}{2} = 16 \; , \; -9 $$
So $x^2$  is either $16$ or $-9,$  and we demanded $x$ real, so
$ x = 4$  from which $2xy = 24$ says $y=3$
So, that is one square root, $4+3i$  while the second is $-4-3i$
$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$
Starting over,  second square root  of $4 + 3 i$
$$   x^2 - y^2  = 4 \; , \; \; \; 2xy = 3  $$

Totally forgot about that way, thanks a lot man.

Let $z = r \operatorname{cis}(\theta)$ be one of the roots.  Then, by definition of fourth root:
$$(r \operatorname{cis}(\theta))^4 = 7 + 24i$$
Taking the absolute value gives:
$$r^4 = 25$$
$$r = \sqrt{5}$$
So now, we can just divide by $r^4 = 25$ to get an equation for $\theta$.
$$\operatorname{cis}(\theta)^4 = \frac{7}{25} + \frac{24}{25}i$$
Now, let's expand $\operatorname{cis}(\theta)$ to $c + is$, where $c = \cos(\theta)$ and $s = \sin(\theta)$.  Then:
$$(c+is)^4 = \frac{7}{25} + \frac{24}{25}i$$
$$c^4 + 4ic^3s - 6c^2s^2 - 4ics^3 + s^4 = \frac{7}{25} + \frac{24}{25}i$$
Breaking this down into real and imaginary parts gives:
$$c^4 - 6c^2s^2 + s^4 = \frac{7}{25} \tag{1}$$
$$4c^3s - 4cs^3 = \frac{24}{25} \tag{2}$$
We can simplify equation (1) by using the Pythagorean identity $c^2 + s^2 = 1$ and replace $c^2 \to 1 - s^2$.
$$(1-s^2)^2 - 6(1-s^2)s^2 + s^4 = \frac{7}{25}$$
$$1 - 2s^2 + s^4 - 6s^2 + 6s^4 + s^4 = \frac{7}{25}$$
$$8s^4 - 8s^2 + 1 - \frac{7}{25} = 0$$
$$200s^4 - 200s^2 + 18 = 0$$
$$100s^4 - 100s^2 + 9 = 0$$
Using the quadratic formula to solve for $s^2$ gives:
$$s^2 = \frac{-(-100) \pm \sqrt{(-100)^2-4(100)(9)}}{2(100)}$$
$$s^2 = \frac{100 \pm \sqrt{6400}}{200}$$
$$s^2 = \frac{100 \pm 80}{200}$$
$$s^2 = \frac{9}{10} \text{ or } s^2 = \frac{1}{10}$$
$$s = \pm\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} \text{ or } s = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$$
But since $c^2 = 1 - s^2$, then:
$$c^2 = \frac{1}{10} \text{ or } c^2 = \frac{9}{10}$$
$$c = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \text{ or } c = \pm \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$$
So, taking all the combinations of $c$ and $s$ gives 8 potential solutions:
$$c + is \in \{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} + i \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} - i \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} + i \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} - i \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} - i \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}, -\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} + i \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}, -\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}} - i \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \}$$
However, only four of these turn out to also solve equation (2):
$$c + is \in \{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}-i\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}+i\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}, \frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}, -\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}-i\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} \}$$
So now we just need to multiply by $r = \sqrt{5}$ to get the roots.
$$z = r(c + is) \in \{ \frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10}}-i\frac{3\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10}}, -\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10}}+i\frac{3\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10}}, \frac{3\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10}}+i\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10}}, -\frac{3\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10}}-i\frac{\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{10}} \}$$
$$\boxed{z \in \{ \frac{1 - 3i}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{-1+3i}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{3+i}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{-3-i}{\sqrt{2}} \}}$$

You meant $c+is$ where you typed $c=is$, right?

@J.W.Tanner: Yes.  I just fixed it.
